# How do I create a shortcut to a java application using Wix

Tags: java, xml, wix

How do I create a shortcut that launches a java application with arguments in Wix? This is my current schema and it compiles but doesn't place the shortcut on the desktop.

```
<DirectoryRef Id="DesktopFolder">
    <Component Id="Shortcut" Guid="GUID-HERE">
            <Shortcut
                        Id="desktopFoobarApp" 
                        Name="Foobar 1.0"
                        Directory='DesktopFolder'
                        WorkingDirectory='INSTALLDIR'
                        Target="java"
                        Arguments="-jar [INSTALLDIR]FoobarApp.jar -v -f [INSTALLDIR]conf.cfg"
                        Icon="icon.ico" />
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Microsoft\FoobarApp" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="0" KeyPath="yes"/>                                                     
    </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found out that you need to add the entire path to the target. The following code works:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="DesktopFolder">
    <Component Id="Shortcut" Guid="GUID-HERE">
            <Shortcut
                        Id="desktopFoobarApp" 
                        Name="Foobar 1.0"
                        Directory='DesktopFolder'
                        WorkingDirectory='INSTALLDIR'
                        Target="[System64Folder]javaw.exe"
                        Arguments='-jar "[INSTALLDIR]FoobarApp.jar" -v -f "[INSTALLDIR]conf.cfg"'
                        Icon="icon.ico" />
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Microsoft\FoobarApp" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="0" KeyPath="yes"/>                                                     
    </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put `<Shortcut>` tag between `<File>` tag

Try this:

```
</File Id="id" Name="file name" Source="file source path">
    <Shortcut Id="desktopFoobarApp"  Name="Foobar 1.0" Directory='DesktopFolder'
              WorkingDirectory='INSTALLDIR' Target="java"
              Arguments="-jar [INSTALLDIR]FoobarApp.jar -v -f [INSTALLDIR]conf.cfg"
              Icon="icon.ico" />
</File>
```

Comment: You can't use the Target attribute when next in a File element.

error CNDL0062 :
The Shortcut/@Target attribute cannot be specified when the Shortcut element is nested underneath a File element.

Comment: The Shortcut/@Target attribute is formatted. Because it has defined `source` in `<File>`, just remove `target` attribute

Comment: But the file needs to be launched by java. the source is a jar. how does the shortcut know to launch the file via the java binary if you remove it?